# Where does Minecraft save its data?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I bought Minecraft on the Microsoft Store. I would like to download some mods but I cannot find my Minecraft folder anywhere.

I am running Windows 10. Where is it?

Answer (score -1):

Click Start → Run. If you don't see "Run" try holding down your "Windows" key and press the R key.

Type %appdata% (case doesn't matter but be sure to include the % markers) and click OK.

Open the .minecraft folder.

Comment: i did and still didnt see it

Comment: How does simply going to the appdata folder tell OP where the data is? Isn't the save location configurable anyways?

Comment: i found the folder but its telling me on forge when i try to install it that minecraft isnt instaled when it is

Comment: @CheyenneWetzel You need to go to %appdata% got to .minecraft in there there should be a mods folder inside (if forge is installed) thats were you need to put your mods then you need to make sure your running the right version of minecraft for your mods.